# How to generate a Blazor component dynamically on a click of a button?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working with Blazor server. I have a `ButtonComponent` which displays a button and the user can pass in a label as a parameter via a modal window and then click <kbd>Ok</kbd>.
Once the user clicks <kbd>Ok</kbd>, the label typed in gets displayed on the button.

How can I display multiple components vertically(`ButtonComponent`)
when the user clicks the <kbd>Show Button</kbd> one at a time?

```
@page "/tester"

<button type="button" @onclick="() => showSignUpComponent = true">
    Show Button
</button>

@if (showSignUpComponent)
{
    <ButtonComponent label="Search" /> <hr/>
}

@code {
    bool showSignUpComponent;
}
```

Comment: Without any variation (parameters) in the buttons it is not very useful. Make a better mockup.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than thinking of collections of controls, think of `Lists` of objects that need to be expressed in markup.  So, if you have a collection of Label strings that need buttons, you can do something like:

```
@page "/btn"

<input @bind="newLabel" />

<button type="button" @onclick="() => Labels.Add(newLabel) ">
    Spawn
</button>

@foreach (var label in Labels)
{
    @*<ButtonComponent label="@label" />*@
    <div>This would be a button with label "@label".</div>
}


@code {
    string newLabel { get; set; } = "";

    List<string> Labels = new List<string>();
}
```

You can list any class you want, and swap controls in/out as you need.